# Stephen Abbott "Understanding Analysis" p.81 Exercise 2.8.3.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

I am reading "Understanding Analysis" by Stephen Abbott.
I solved p.81 Exercise 2.8.3.
But I am not sure that my answer is correct.

Is the following answer correct or not?

> Let $\{a_{ij} : i, j \in \mathbb{N}\}$ be a doubly indexed array of real numbers.
>   Suppose that
>   $$
> \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |a_{ij}|
> $$
>   converges.
>   Let
>   $$
> t_{mn} := \sum_{i=1}^{m} \sum_{j=1}^{n} |a_{ij}|.
> $$
>   Let
>   $$
> s_{mn} := \sum_{i=1}^{m} \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{ij}.
> $$
>
> Exercise 2.8.3
>   (a) Prove that $(t_{nn})$ converges
>   (b) Now, use the fact that $(t_{nn})$ is a Cauchy sequence to argue that $(s_{nn})$ converges.

(a) For any $i \in \{1, 2, 3, \cdots \}$,
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{n} |a_{ij}| \leq \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |a_{ij}|.
$$
So, 
$$
t_{nn} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} |a_{ij}| \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |a_{ij}| \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |a_{ij}|.
$$
So $(t_{nn})$ converges.

(b) $$| \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{ij} - \sum_{i=1}^{m} \sum_{j=1}^{m} a_{ij} | \leq | \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} |a_{ij}| - \sum_{i=1}^{m} \sum_{j=1}^{m} |a_{ij}| |.$$
$(t_{nn})$ is a Cauchy sequence by assumption,
so $(s_{nn})$ is also a Cauchy sequence from the above inequality.

Comment: Your answer to (a) only shows that $t_{nn}$ is bounded, not that it converges. Also, note that the fact that $t_{nn}$ is Cauchy is not an assumption -- you should have proved it in (a).